# How does the descending branch of the loop of Henle equilibrate concentration?

Tags: physiology, human-physiology, kidney

I'm learning physiology and I have a hard time figuring out how the cortico-papillary gradient is created.

Most explanations go as follow:
**1)** Sodium is pumped out the ascending branch into the interstitium until a 200 mOsm/L gradient is established between the tubular fluid and the interstitium.
**2)** Water passively flows from the descending branch into the interstitium to equilibrate osmolarity between the tubular fluid and the interstitum.
**3)** The tubular fluid flows, moving everything towards the ascending branch.
**1 bis)** Sodium is again pumped out until the 200 mOsm/L gradient is established
Reapeating this steps over and over again creates the vertical gradient.

This is illustrated here
[image: Creation of the cortico-papillary osmotic gradient]

Ok, so far, so good; here comes my question :
**In step 2, how comes the final concentrations in the interstitium and the tubular fluid in the descending branch are equal to the initial concentration in the interstitium?**
I would expect the final concentration to be the mean of the two. In the examples above, starting from 400 mOsm/L in the interstitium and 300 mOsm/L in the descending branch, I would expect 350 mOsm/L at the end, not 400 mOsm/L.

How is that possible? Is this because at every moment, when water flows into the interstitium diluting its content, the ascending branch keeps pumping sodium to maintain the 200 mOsm/L gradient?

Thanks a million to whoever will answer this question!